# React-Native Flatlist not rendering when record is single

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My React-Native Flatlist have refused render data when my json data is just one. My flatlist renders properly when the data on my Json is more than one.

I have tried all the ricks i can think of but yet, its not working.
This is happening to all the Flatlist in all my program and its sickining already.

I have tried getting the array side using `Object.keys(jsonResponse.Product).length;`
before choosing to either render to a Flatlist or return a single data View which refused to also work for me as the Object.key returns the same size when the data item is one and same when its two. (really strange)

I have also tried effecting the styling of the Flatlist my using
`height:((Dimensions.get('screen').height))` and `width:((Dimensions.get('screen').width))`
in the Flatlist  **contentContainerStyle** props, yet it does not render when data is single

Also tried using `Array.from()` to make sure that the data the flatlist will render is well converted to an object/array

I have also tried using `this.state.PC_list_data.map()` which still does not render when the data item is just one (single) like the flatlist

**JSON OUTPUT WHEN DATA IS MORE THAN ONE**
[image]

**JSON SINGLE OUTPUT**
[image]

```
render(){

        return(<FlatList
                                    contentContainerStyle={{
                                        borderWidth: 0,
                                        width:((Dimensions.get('screen').width)),
                                        //height:((Dimensions.get('screen').height))+50,
                                        borderColor:'#00d',
                                       // marginTop:30
                                    }}

                                    data={ Array.from(this.state.PC_list_data) || []}
                                    keyExtractor={(item) =>item.Product_id}
                                    renderItem={({item,index})=>
                                    {

                                        return (<CategoryProduct_List
                                                {...item}
                                                List_index={index}
                                                HrefNav={this.navigateToSubProduct.bind(this, {...item})}
                                            />
                                        )}

                                    }


                                />)

      }
```

///CODE ON THE *CategoryProduct_List* Component

```
const CategoryProduct_List = props =>
{ 
           //alert('aaa')

    return (<View style={[{
        flex: 1,
        display:'flex',

        flexDirection: "row",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(243,243,243)',
        marginHorizontal:10,
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        alignItem:'center',
        borderLeftWidth:10,
        borderLeftColor:'#80146D',
        marginBottom:10,
        marginLeft:5+'%',
        marginTop:5,
        padding:10,
        width: 90+'%',
        height:100+'%'

    }]}>


        <View style={{
            alignItem:"left",
        }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={()=> props.HrefNav()}>
                <Text>{props.Product_name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end",}}>

            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.7}>
                <IconSet  color='#80146D' onPress={()=> props.HrefNav()}   size={25} name="arrow-forward"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>



    </View>);

}

export default CategoryProduct_List;
```

What i want to know is how i can make the Flatlist render my single records and what i am not doing right here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be flatlist, since it works with one item ... it may be the data

Some API's return an array of json for multiple data Ex: `[{1...},{2...},{3...}]` and that is well received by the faltlist component. But when requesting only one item , the apis return an individual json Ex: `{1...}` , and faltlist only accepts an array of json, not an individual json...

For that you can use a validator  function that will check if the data is array, or an individual json , and call it before using it as the flatlist data. it would help if you placed the response from both an item group, or an individual item

```
function format(data){
var result = []
if(!Array.isArray(data)){//if is not an array
   result.push(data) // push it as the first item of an array
}else{
 result=data
}

return result
}
```

can you post a sample of `this.state.PC_list_data` when you have 1 item and when you have  multiple items please?

Comment: i tried using Array.from() to make sure that the data the flatlist will render is well converted to an object/array whch did not work...

Let me trying using ur data formating method and see if it will work

Comment: You are very right. Your code worked like a charm.., Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

i also face this problem

**Solution :**

some time flatlist cant't be show single record you have to add extra data in flatlist

```
<FlatList
   extraData={this.state} />
```

its work fine